# Mysql upgrade from 5.1 to 5.5

Tags: mysql

I am planing to uninstall mysql 5.1 & then install mysql 5.6  over it.
But on official website of mysql , it is showing that slave should be updated before master.
But we are having replication from both ends , means master-master replication is configured 
So which server to upgrade first ?
What approach should be followed to upgrade both the servers ?

And whether their will be any problem in tables , replication , indexes of mysql 5.1 ,  if mysql is upgraded from 5.1 to 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a master-master it's still a two-step process.

This is how I would have done it.

If you have a load-balancer in front, pull one server out of it, or set it to read-only mode, make sure no writes are going there, upgrade it, then restore replication, let it catch up, then upgrade second server (this would actually mean downtime) and then restore master-master replication and enable writes to the first server.